cannot inject RestTemplate when initializing the Bean
I cannot inject RestTemplate when initializing the Bean, restTemplate only NULL.  How do you fix it?

Below is my specific description for configuration and usage.  I greatly appreciate any assistance.
thank u so much <3...``
Config
Use

Image config for spring boot application: Image config

Share code as text not as image

This code is working for me!
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {
    @Value("${sms.kavenegar.timeout.millis}")
    private long timeOutInMilliSeconds;

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeOutInMilliSeconds))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeOutInMilliSeconds))
                .build();
    }
}

maybe your problem is about Duration.ofMillis while you want set time
